# Any API to install add-ins from app store programmatically?

Tags: provider-hosted-app, installation, pnp-powershell, alm

I have two questions:

1. Is there any API like [ALM API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/alm-api-for-spfx-add-ins) to install provider hosted add-ins from app store?
2. Even if I install it manually, `Get-PnPApp` does not return the id of apps installed from app store so no help there too [More Details](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1738)

Any clue if it is possible to automate this?